# Error in pandas while subtracting two values and storing them again

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

```
First.csv
LAC Reference_Count
1000    500
2222    1000
3333    500
5555    1000
9999    1500

Second.csv
LAC 10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
1000    2000    2500
2222    3000    4000
```

I have two files first.csv and second.csv,in first.csv I have two headers LAC and reference count,second.csv no of header can be in any number but it will follow one format that is one column with LAC all ids, followed by time date series,I need to take LAC(id) from second.csv and search in LAC of first.csv take the reference count and subtract value of all time series of second.csv. You can better understand with expected output.

```
second.csv 
    LAC  10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
0  1000            1500            2000
1  2222            2000            3000
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
location='/home/saiharsh/Documents/Crowd Street/BUgs/second.py.csv'
master_lac_path='/home/saiharsh/Documents/Crowd Street/Final/first.csv'
master_csv_file = master_lac_path
df_master=pd.read_csv(master_csv_file,error_bad_lines=False)
df2=pd.read_csv(location,error_bad_lines=False)
header=list(df2.iloc[:,1:].columns.values)
print df2
for i in range(len(df2)):
            val=df_master[df_master['LAC']==df2['LAC'][i]]['Reference_Count']
            for j in header:
                Tmp=df2[j][i]
                tmp=df2[df2[j]==Tmp][j]
                value=tmp-val
                print type(tmp),type(val),type(value)
                df2.set_value(i,j,value)
print df2
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Py_Process_Plots/master_lac.py", line 14, in process
    value=tmp-val
  File "/home/software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 524, in wrapper
    arr = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/home/software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 475, in na_op
    result[mask] = op(x[mask], _values_from_object(y[mask]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

My pandas version is 0.16.2 and numpy is 1.9.2

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting everything to float as the error is saying that you have a string that you are trying to do math with.

Did you try:

```
float(value) = float(tmp) - float(val)
```

Let me know if the error changes after that. Post the error too.

Comment: Any kind of solution to solve it. It tried int() but doesn't work

Comment: Even I have already tried it, Error is`Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "main.py", 
line 55, 
in <module> process() File "main.py", 
line 46, 
in process master_lac.process(tmp,master_lac_path) File "/home/Py_Process_Plots/master_lac.py", line 18, in process tmp=float(tmp) File "/home/software/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 77, in wrapper "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter))) TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('First.csv', sep='\t', header=0, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('Second.csv', sep='\t', header=0, index_col=0)
dfans = df2.subtract(df1.iloc[:,0], axis=0).dropna()

print(df1)
      Reference_Count
LAC                  
1000              500
2222             1000
3333              500
5555             1000
9999             1500

print(df2)
      10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
LAC                                 
1000            2000            2500
2222            3000            4000

print(dfans)
      10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
LAC                                 
1000            1500            2000
2222            2000            3000
```

You need to have LAC as your index.  The following does not work...

```
index_default = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', header=0)

print(index_default)
    LAC  10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
0  2222            3000            4000
1  1000            2000            2500

dfans = index_default.subtract(df1.iloc[:,0], axis=0).dropna()

print(dfans)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [LAC, 10/08/15 00:00, 10/08/15 01:00]
Index: []
```

But with LAC as index, it works...

```
index_lac = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', header=0, index_col=0)

print(index_lac)
      10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
LAC                                 
2222            3000            4000
1000            2000            2500

dfans = index_lac.subtract(df1.iloc[:,0], axis=0).dropna()

print(dfans)
      10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
LAC                                 
1000            1500            2000
2222            2000            3000
```

Comment: **It's not working when input is**                                                                                      `LAC  10/08/15 00:00  10/08/15 01:00
0  2222            3000            4000
1  1000            2000            2500`

Comment: In your question you have pandas create an index for you.  In your comment you also have pandas creating an index for you.  If you use 'index_col=0' instead then LAC will be your index and then it should work.